# Out of Memory using Java API but Cypher query can work although it is slow

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph database with 150 million nodes and a few hundred million relationships.

There are two types of nodes in the network: account node and transaction node. Each account node has a public key and each transaction node has a number (the amount of total bitcoin involved in this transaction).

There are also two types of relationships in the network. Each relationship connects an account node with a transaction node. One type of relationships is "send" and the other type is "receive". Each relationship also has a number to represent how much bitcoin it sends or receives.

This is an example:

```
(account: publickey = A)-[send: bitcoin=1.0]->(transaction :id = 1, Tbitcoin=1.0)-[receive: bitcoin=0.5]->(account: publickey = B)
(account: publickey = A)-[send: bitcoin=1.0]->(transaction :id = 1, Tbitcoin=1.0)-[receive: bitcoin=0.5]->(account: publickey = C)
```

As you can imagine, `B` or `C` can also send or receive bitcoins to or from other accounts which involves many different transactions.

What I wants to do is to find all paths with depth equaling to 4 between two accounts, e.g. `A` and `C`.  I can do this by Cypher although it is slow. It takes about 20mins. My cypher is like this:

```
start src=node:keys(PublicKey="A"),dest=node:keys(PublicKey="C") 
match p=src-->(t1)-->(r1)-->(t2)-->dest 
return count(p);
```

However, when I try to do that using Java API, I got the `OutOfMemoryError`. Here is my function:

```
  public ArrayList<Path> getPathsWithConditionsBetweenNodes(String indexName, String sfieldName, String sValue1, String sValue2,
        int depth, final double threshold, String relType){

    ArrayList<Path> res = null;
    if (isIndexExistforNode(indexName)) {
        try (Transaction tx = graphDB.beginTx()) {
            IndexManager index = graphDB.index();
            Index<Node> accounts = index.forNodes(indexName);
            IndexHits<Node> hits = null;
            hits = accounts.get(sfieldName, sValue1);
            Node src = null, dest = null;
            if(hits.iterator().hasNext())
                src = hits.iterator().next();
            hits = null;
            hits = accounts.get(sfieldName, sValue2);
            if(hits.iterator().hasNext())
                dest = hits.iterator().next();
            if(src==null || dest==null){
                System.out.println("Either src or dest node is not avaialble.");
            }



            TraversalDescription td = graphDB.traversalDescription()
                    .depthFirst();

            if (relType.equalsIgnoreCase("send")) {
                td = td.relationships(Rels.Send, Direction.OUTGOING);
                td = td.relationships(Rels.Receive, Direction.OUTGOING);
            } else if (relType.equalsIgnoreCase("receive")) {
                td= td.relationships(Rels.Receive,Direction.INCOMING);
                td = td.relationships(Rels.Send,Direction.INCOMING);
            } else {
                System.out
                        .println("Traverse Without Type Constrain Because Unknown Relationship Type is Provided to The Function.");
            }

            td = td.evaluator(Evaluators.includingDepths(depth, depth))
                    .uniqueness(Uniqueness.RELATIONSHIP_PATH)
                    .evaluator(Evaluators.returnWhereEndNodeIs(dest));




                td = td.evaluator(new Evaluator() {
                    @Override
                    public Evaluation evaluate(Path path) {

                        if (path.length() == 0) {
                            return Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
                        } else {

                            Node node = path.endNode();
                            if (!node.hasProperty("TBitcoin"))
                                return Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
                            double coin = (double) node.getProperty("TBitcoin");

                            if (threshold!=Double.MIN_VALUE) {
                                if (coin<=threshold) {
                                    return Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_PRUNE;
                                } else {
                                    return Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
                                }
                            } else {
                                return Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }); 



            res = new ArrayList<Path>();
            int i=0;
            for(Path path : td.traverse(src)){
                i++;
                //System.out.println(path);

                //res.add(path);
            }
            System.out.println();
            tx.success();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        ;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Can someone take a look at my function and give me some ideas why it is so slow and will cause out-of-memory error? I set `Xmx=15000m` while runing this program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My $0.02 is that you shouldn't do this with java, you should do it with Cypher.  But your query needs some work.  Here's your basic query:

```
start src=node:keys(PublicKey="A"),dest=node:keys(PublicKey="C") 
match p=src-->(t1)-->(r1)-->(t2)-->dest 
return count(p);
```

There are at least two problems with this:

- The intermediate r1 could be the same as your original src, or your original dest (which probably isn't what you want, you're looking for intermediaries)
- You don't specify that t1 or t2 are send or receive.  Meaning that you're forcing cypher to match both kinds of edges.  Meaning cypher has to look through a lot more stuff to give you your answer.

Here's how to tighten your query so it should perform much better:

```
start src=node:keys(PublicKey="A"),dest=node:keys(PublicKey="C") 
match p=src-[:send]->(t1:transaction)-[:receive]->(r1)-[:send]->(t2:transaction)-[:receive]->dest 
where r1 <> src and 
      r1 <> dest
return count(p);
```

This should prune out a lot of possible edge and node traversals that you're currently doing, that you don't need to be doing.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will definitely try your query and keep you updated! Would you please tell me why this should not be done with Java? Isn't that the core API has better performance than Cypher? Sorry that I am new to Neo4j.

Comment: What you're trying to express takes a lot of complex java, and it's not that hard in cypher.  So cypher because it's easier to write, and to maintain.   Your traversal code in java will have to be very smart and carefully written to do as well as cypher will do, since it's ultimately using the same traversal.  Cypher is "declarative" - say *WHAT* you want, and it goes and gets it.  The java is "imperative" - you have to say *HOW* to get it (traversal).  If you can get away with acceptable performance on declarative query, it's usually better.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Will keep you posted on this matter.

Comment: Hi FrobberOfBits, thanks for the suggestions. I have tried your query and it takes about 1000 second to complete. It's faster than my original query. So thank you a lot! But I am wondering is this what Neo4j can do? My entire database including all the indexes is about 36 GB in disk. I only have 15 GB memory in the machine. So, obviously, I can't load everything into memory. But I still feel that 20mins for a query is too long.

Comment: You said you have 150 million nodes and a few hundred million relationships.   1,000 seconds is less than 17 minutes, which really doesn't seem that bad to me considering how much data you have.   To speed up your query further, make sure you have good indexes on the public key, and add as many more selective criteria to the query as you can, to reduce the total number of things it must look at.   Also, if this is the best answer, please mark it accepted for people who search later.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood what you are trying to achieve and because you have a direction on your relationship I think that you can get away with something quite simple:

```
MATCH (src:keys{publickey:'A')-[r:SEND|RECEIVE*4]->(dest:keys{publickey:'C'})
RETURN COUNT(r)
```

Depending on your data set @FrobberOfBits makes a good point regarding testing equality of intermediaries which you cannot do using this approach, however with just the two transactions you are testing for cases where a Transaction source and destination are the same (`r1 <> src` and `r1 <> dest`), which may not even be valid in your model. If you were testing 3 or more transactions then things would get more interesting as you might want to exclude paths like `(A)-->(T1)-->(B)-->(T2)-->(A)-->(T3)-->(C)`

Shameless theft:

```
MATCH path=(src:keys{publickey:'A')-[r:SEND|RECEIVE*6]->(dest:keys{publickey:'C'})
WHERE ALL (n IN NODES(path) 
       WHERE (1=LENGTH(FILTER(m IN NODES(path) 
                              WHERE m=n))))
RETURN COUNT(path)
```

Or traversal (caveat, pseudo code, never used it):

```
PathExpander expander = PathExapnder.forTypesAndDirections("SEND", OUTGOING, "RECEIVE", OUTGOING)
PathFinder<Path> finder = GraphAlgoFactory.allSimplePaths(expander, 6);
Iterable<Path> paths = finder.findAllPaths(src, dest);
```